# NavigationBarViewController Storyboard example

Tags: cosmicmind

I want to build my layout using storyboards but also use the implementation of Material. But I have trouble to understand how to use the NavigationBarViewController with Storyboards.

Can you create an example for Storyboard using the NavigationBarViewController with transition between views? Is it possible to use segues?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague, but yes, you can segue (and usually do in any complex app) between views while contained in a navigation controller.  The navigation controller will persist between these views unless you are segueing using modals.

Comment: I know how to use storyboards with segues in a regular way, but wondered if it was possible using Material. (removed the ios and swift tags)

Comment: @sverin, We will work on an example that shows how to use a NavigationBarViewController with storyboards :)

Comment: @CosmicMind Great, I'm looking forward to it.